# Python Memory Error when creating numpy zeros array with size(100000,2,50,50,50)

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I wanted to create a numpy zeros array:

```
result = np.zeros(( 100000, 2) +  (50,50,50), dtype="float64")
```

However,it said 'MemoryError'

I was running this script on a linux cluster, whose memory info is:

> svmem(total=405542666240, available=386684821504, percent=4.7, used=16979877888, free=5489012736, active=105578418176, inactive=255886082048, buffers=966123520, cached=382107652096, shared=2473984, slab=34765426688)

And this code works well on my own laptop,which has a much smaller memory size:

> svmem(total=8589934592, available=2469203968, percent=71.3, used=4809822208, free=16855040, active=2450419712, inactive=2442956800, wired=2359402496)

I am using numpy-64 bit. I think the array size might be too large,but why can I run this code on my own laptop,whose memory is very limited?
Is there any way to rewrite the code?

Comment: May there so limit on size of virtual address space per process on this system

Comment: That's over 186 gigabytes!  I'm sure your laptop would run into some problems if you actually wrote to any substantial fraction of that array.  You might (or might not) get away with the mere allocation of such an array as long as it stays virtual.

Comment: Check overcommit policy https://serverfault.com/questions/606185/how-does-vm-overcommit-memory-work

Comment: Thanks.Maybe there is a limitation set by the cluster administrator. I reduced the size to (1e4,2,50,50,50) and it works. Thanks for your help.